# Настройки Collider 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что при повороте персонажа, коллайдер остается на исходном положении, можно ли изменить это как-то ?[image: Вот скриншоты]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у тебя неправильно сам спрайт настроен. При флипе (повороте), спрайт (картинка) поворачивается относительно оси, которая проходит через pivot или origin. В настройках коллайдера видно, что его центр смещен влево. Попробуй сначала настроить спрайт в редакторе [Sprite Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/SpriteEditor.html), чтобы pivot был по центру персонажа. Затем положи коллайдер по центру. тогда все будет гуд при флипах

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло <3

Comment: Рад помочь. Не забудьте отметить ответ как верный, если помогло ) спс